# Filter and match cell to calculate weight of a product (Excel, Google Sheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

`Im new here and in the world of Excel.`
I`m stuck with a problem and even describing the problem is problematic :D

So here goes:

I have 2 sheets (**sheet1 & sheet2**) in sheet2 **column A** has a list of items (item1, item2, item3, etc). **Column B** has a list of weigh for each unit (so ***item1*** 2kg per unit, ***item3*** 0.2kg per unit...etc).

Sheet1 has **columnA** with a dropdown from all the products from Sheet2 and a cell in cloumnB with how many units have been bought (manual input). **ColumnC** has to be able to calculate the weight based on the product and units selected.

So if I select from dropdown list on **sheet1** a product: **item1** and in the next cell I specify that I have bought 10 units I need that **columnC** updates to 20 kg.

`How I see the formula is that it compares the **sheet1** columnA with **sheet2** columnA finds the match and multiplies the units with the weight per unit from **sheet2** and updates the field in **sheet1** columnC.`

Please help.

Comment: Yes, as Tefalpan suggested, worked like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula in column C of sheet 1:

```
=B1*VLOOKUP(A1;sheet2!A1:B999;2)
```

Extra info: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Comment: Thank you so much! Had to use "false" at the end of the function, as it was returning weird numbers. And thank you for the link! Great reading :)

Comment: Could you mark this as an answer (checkmark) , this 'closes' this question :)

Comment: Done! Thanks Tefalpan